# Apk file is not updated in emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I'm programming in eclipse juno. I've written an android application about half-a-year ago, and tested it on the emulator, and it worked fine. Now im looking again in this application, and for some reason, it is not updated! No matter what i do! I've even deleted the apk, but nothing!

What can i do?

## EDIT

I don't know what i did, but now the application doesn't start in the emulator! Only black screen when I click on it! Help please...

Comment: Have you tried "Fix project properties" and creating new AVD?

Comment: try  adb ta project clean, which will delete the apk from your computer, then go to cmd, go to platform tools and write "adb uninstall com.yourpackage.yourappname and then try running the app again, it should force the adb to do a clean install. I get this problem sometimes too, it says "application already installed, no need to reinstall"